# Non-Hausdorff Space With Only One Limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for an example of a non-Hausdorff topological space where every convergent sequence converges to the same point. In other words, if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent sequences in $X$, then they both converge to the point $x \in X$.

Does one exist?

Comment: I can only think of indiscrete space where every sequence converges to every point.

Comment: @drhab $X = \mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$, with the topology $\{ U : U \subset \mathbb{N}\text{ or } U = X\}$. // If the set of limits of all convergent sequences shall be the same, then the space must be indiscrete, but if the intersection of the limit sets only needs to be nonempty, there are more interesting examples.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see now. Thank you for making me a bit wiser in topology (you did it earlyer also).

Comment: Do you require that there is a point $x\in X$ such that every convergent sequence converges to $x$ (and to also perhaps some other points)? Or, do you mean that for every two converging sequences there is a point $x$ such that both converge to $x$? Note every constant sequence $a,a,a,\dots$ is convergent (to $a$, and perhaps to some other points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology. Then any sequence $a_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Any sequence converges to $1$ also.

Comment: @ArpanSadhukhan yes, but this isn't problematic. Reread the question.

Comment: the question says that both sequences should converge to the point $x\in X$, which is THE point $x$ in your example?

Comment: @Mirko Every sequence converges to THE point $0$.

Comment: But both sequence also converge to $1$. So what is the $x$, as stated in the OP? I could clearly say what is the point $x$ in Daniel Fischer's example in a comment, but not in your answer.

Comment: @Mirko I think you are misunderstanding the question. Nowhere does it say that every sequence must converge to a singular, unique point. So in my example, $x=0$ or $x=1$. Whichever you feel stronger about.

Comment: "every convergent sequence converges to the same point" clearly implies that the point $x$ must be unique. I do not think I misunderstand the question. I am not the only one who objected your solution in a comment. Perhaps you are misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Look at the criterion for what it means for a sequence to converge to THE point $0$. Then take any two sequences and apply the definition. You will see that they both converge to THE same point $0$.